# Retrieve Service principal and Client Secret during creation using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm creating new secret in Azure (app registry) and have a problem to store new secret vault.
Th code looks like below:

```
      $Pass = New-Guid | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
      $Credential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential
      $Credential.KeyId = [guid]::NewGuid()
      $Credential.EndDateTime = $(Get-Date).AddMonths(6)
      $Credential.DisplayName = "Created by script"
      $secret=Update-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId  "myAPPid" -PasswordCredential $Credential
```

Using code above I'm able to create new secrets for SPN but value $secret is empty, I tried New-AzADAppCredential but it will create new SPN for me not update secret in existing one.
I know it is not possible to retrieve already created secrets but how to catch secret during creation or reset using powershell command ?

UPDATE
New-AzADAppCredential is a solution

Comment: Azure is now using OAUTH2 authentication.  Your cmdlet may be old.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2.  The registry setting probably have changed since the update for OAUTH2.

Answer (score 0):

I would not spend any time in automating the creation of secrets. Developers should no longer rely on secrets.

There are better ways, certificates or managed identities. If you must, you can create a secret in the portal.

Here is a script how to upload the public key of a certificate, https://github.com/svrooij/powershell-snippits/blob/main/graph/app-only-access.ps1

In that [repository](https://github.com/svrooij/powershell-snippits) you can also find a CodeTour that explains all the steps. And samples on how to use the new Graph powershell modules.